# Why some class variables seem to act as static while others don't?

Tags: python

Dictionaries and lists defined directly under the class definition act as static (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045246/python-and-object-class-attrs-whats-going-on))
How come other variables such as integer do not?

```
>>> class Foo():
        bar=1

>>> a=Foo()
>>> b=Foo()
>>> a.bar=4
>>> b.bar
1
>>> class Foo():
        bar={}

>>> a=Foo()
>>> b=Foo()
>>> a.bar[7]=8
>>> b.bar
{7: 8}
```

Comment: check Omnifarious answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701500/python-class-instance-variables-and-class-variables/8701647#8701647)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are all class variables. Except for when you assigned `a.bar=4` creating an instance variable. Basically Python has a lookup order on attributes. It goes:

```
instance -> class -> parent classes in MRO order (left to right)
```

So if you have

```
class Foo(object):
    bar = 1
```

This is a variable on the class Foo. Once you do

```
a = Foo()
a.bar = 2
```

you have created a new variable on the object `a` with the name `bar`. If you look at `a.__class__.bar` you will still see 1, but it is effectively hidden due to the order mentioned earlier.

The dict you created is at the class-level so it is shared between all instances of that class.

Answer (score 6):

When you make the assignment

```
>>> a.bar=4
```

you are *rebinding* the `Foo.bar` name to `4`, which is a new instance of an integer. On the other hand,

```
>>> a.bar[7]=8
```

Does not rebind `Foo.bar` to anything different, and simply modifies the dictionary that the name refers to.

If you do

```
>>> a.bar = {7: 8}
```

then you will rebind `Foo.bar` to a *new* dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `a` is an instance of `A` and `A` has a class attribute `bar`:

- `a.bar = 4` creates an instance attribute `bar` which hides the class `bar` in the context of `a`
- `a.bar[4] = 2` only modifies the object that the class-level `bar` binds to (assuming it supports indexing)
- `a.bar += 1` - This one is **nasty**. If the class-level `bar` supports the `+=` operation (e.g. by implementing `__iadd__()`), then it is modified in-place and no object-level attribute is created. Otherwise it is equivalent to `a.bar = a.bar + 1` and a new instance attribute `bar` is created.